# list from <propertyselector> does not work with <for>

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am having a difficulty getting the following Apache Ant script to work. The idea is to copy property values from properties with a certain prefix to properties without the prefix.

```xml
<project name="scp.result.files">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />

    <property name="prop.a.sub1" value="a" />
    <property name="prop.b.extra2" value="b" />
    <property name="prop.c.foo" value="c" />
    <property name="prop.d.foo" value="not selected" />

    <target name="prep-props">
        <!-- Select all interesting properties. -->
        <propertyselector property="prop.list"
                          delimiter=","
                          match="prop\.(a|b|c)\..+"
                          casesensitive="false"
                          override="true" />
        <echo message="matched properties: ${prop.list}" />

        <!-- For each selected property, set a property without the "prop." prefix. -->
        <for param="prop" list="${prop.list}" delimiter="," trim="true">
            <propertyregex property="dest.prop"
                           input="@{prop}"
                           regex="prop\.((a|b|c)\..+)"
                           select="\1"
                           overrride="true" />
            <propertycopy name="${dest.prop}"
                          from="prop.${dest.prop}"
                          override="true" />
            <propertycopy name="_pval" from="${dest.prop}" override="true" />
            <echo message="${dest.prop} is ${_pval}" />
        </for>
    </target>
</project>
```

Unfortunately, the above script produces the following error for me.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\test.xml:19: Invalid type class net.sf.antcontrib.property.RegexTask used in For task, it does not have a public iterator method
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask$ReflectIterator.<init>(ForTask.java:450)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.add(ForTask.java:411)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$13.create(IntrospectionHelper.java:1552)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$Creator.create(IntrospectionHelper.java:1329)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChild(UnknownElement.java:574)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.java:358)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.configure(UnknownElement.java:204)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Is it possible to fix this? Is there any other way of iterating over the selected properties list and getting the un-prefixed properties set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of tasks to execute for each iteration of `for` needs to be placed inside a `sequential` element, otherwise the `propertyregex` will be considered as a "list" the `for` task will iterate on. Also the [`propertyregex`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) uses `regexp` instead of `regex` (checking its documentation).

```
<for param="prop" list="${prop.list}" delimiter="," trim="true">
    <sequential>
        <propertyregex property="dest.prop"
                   input="@{prop}"
                   regexp="prop\.((a|b|c)\..+)"
                   select="\1"
                   overrride="true" />
        <propertycopy name="${dest.prop}"
                   from="prop.${dest.prop}"
                   override="true" />
        <propertycopy name="_pval" from="${dest.prop}" override="true" />
        <echo message="${dest.prop} is ${_pval}" />
    </sequential>
</for>
```